# /var/log suspicious entries

Tags: networking, ssh, security

For fun I tailed `/var/log/auth.log` (tail auth.log) and there were many of the following:

```
 sshd[16225]: Received disconnect from 203.100.83.32: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
```

The ip appears to be from China...

I added iptables rule to block the ip and is now gone.

Now seeing the following:

```
 sshd[17225]: fatal: Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer [preauth]
```

What are both entries and what can I do to protect or dynamically see threats.
I do have `fail2ban` installed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need the `ssh` port open on the public side? What was the rule added in `iptables`? Having `ssh` exposed to the public side is going to generate a lot of hits from port sniffers and crackbots, which may be the cause of the entries you're seeing now.

Comment: The server is hosted at Linode.com, I ssh to the box to manage, change, and do everything, so I need ssh for now.  I added an iptables rule to block the /24 address from China.  But I need to be more secure and not worry about hackers so much.

Comment: You could use a very low-threshold setting in `fail2ban` for failed `ssh` logins - 2 or 3 fails before banning - with a short ban time (10-15 minutes) to discourage the crackbots but not too long to leave you locked out if you pooch a login attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need access to this host from multiple locations?  Or can you use a jumpbox that has a static IP?  If this is the case, you can set an iptables rule that only allows SSH access to a specific IP(s).  This will give you implicit deny to anyone except the static IPs.

The other recommendations would be to change the service to listen on a non-standard port, disable root authentication, and configure fail2ban.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your sshd port to 1000+. Fail2ban helps too.

For example i have some servers running sshd on 1919 or 905 and I barely get these chinese IPs trying to bruteforce my servers.